# How to expand PageView image to match image's height and width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making image viewer with PageView.

But my image is very large and when I set BoxFit.fitWidth, image is beyond screen.

And builder is too small to show entire image.

I think it can be solved by expand width&height of builder.

But I can't find solution.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried BoxFit.contain ?

Comment: Yes. But I want my image's width fit to device's width.

Comment: Yes. I know that and that's what I encountered. Then do i have to use ListView or SinglechildScrollview in PageView?